# Is it common to ask for a screenshot of a competing job offer?

Tags: job-search, job-offer, negotiation

I'm currently looking for a job as a software engineer, and I've received a few offers I'm choosing between. One of them, from a company I'll call Alfa Corp, is much better, so I'm trying to use it to negotiate with another company, Bravo Inc. The person I'm talking to from Bravo says they'll see what they can do, but Alfa's offer is so much better that they expect their manager at Bravo to ask for a screenshot of Alfa's offer letter. This feels weird to me, but I'm not sure. Is asking for a screenshot of a competing job offer normal behavior? Does it depend on the industry? And if it isn't normal, is this something I should be willing to do?

Comment: It's fairly normal to try and determine if someone is lying

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: No, if it's normal practice, I'm happy to – it's just that everyone I've talked to in my immediate circles feels like this is a tremendous overreach by Bravo.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: As I just said, I'm happy to disclose my offer – I already disclosed the numbers, after all, that's how we got here. It's just that in other fields, it seems like this request would be unheard of, and I don't have enough experience here to evaluate if this is a reasonable request from Bravo or a red flag. And you seem to be indicating the former, which is helpful!

Comment: I voted to close as duplicate, but one personal consideration: if the offer from A is so much better, why not take it?

Comment: If the offer from Alfa Corp was better in all respects then you would have accepted it, it obviously is not but you are trying to push for more money from Bravo while Bravo must have other conditions that are better.

Comment: "Is it common" should always have a country tag. "normal" behavior varies greatly from one region to the next.

Answer (score 3):

This is an unusual and unorthodox request. This isn't something I would comply with.

That being said, you probably risk losing the offer from Bravo if you don't comply.

So it's down to a personal decision. Are you willing to lose the offer from Bravo if you don't comply with their request? If you are, then deny their request. If you're not, then comply with it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is not all that common.

Before a company advertises a position they usually do a bit of research to see what other companies are generally offering for similar positions, and then set salary ranges. This means that it shouldn't be all that common that an applicant has an offer from somewhere that is so much higher that they would need to see evidence of such an offer.

Having set a range for the job also means that the company has decided the job has that value - so it is unlikely that they are going to increase their offer beyond that range. I'm surprised they asked for evidence - the typical response would be "well, we can't match that, our best offer is $lower" and they will likely rescind the offer and go to the next candidate.

As for should you do it - I wouldn't. I would just accept the better offer from the other company.